# Print all PHP variables available in template

Tags: magento-1.9, php, template

How can I print all the available PHP variables which I can use in a template?

For example all variables which I can access in `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\wr\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml`

In Laravel for example I could just execute `{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}`
is something similar possible in Magento

Comment: can you specify some more detail.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, I want to print all variables with their values which are sent to the template and can be used. In Laravel for example I could just execute `{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}`

Comment: But in magento phtml file generally it call block function.

Comment: I know that there are block classes. But how can I print all variables with their values from the template for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so is it easy, but try to use the php **get_defined_vars**() function. This returns an array of all defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, apart from:

- Variables you will see defined in the template
- Variables accessible through static methods such as `Mage::app()` (of which there are many
- Various server variables (which you shouldn't be accessing from the template anyway)

`$this` should be the only thing defined - you can print all the data it contains using `var_dump($this->getData())`, however this won't include anything produced by any of the block's methods, for which you'd have to use something like `get_class_methods()`

Answer (score -1):

Use var_dump($this);
Or find in the top of phtml file php variables , and dump them.

Thats all.

Comment: I get `unexpected -> after $`

Comment: I don't understand you